# Usage and meaning of 'would prefer to have+past participle

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning "would prefer to have+past participle " in the following sentences:

1. I would prefer to have stayed at a small family-run hotel than a big international chain.
2. I would prefer to have travelled by train.

In my opinion, both of these sentences express regret, and I think both 'to have stayed' and 'to have travelled' can be replaced by  using 'should have' + past participle.

For example:
1. I should have stayed at a small family-run hotel than a big international -Chain.

2. I should have travelled by train.

I'm not sure and it's just my opinion. So, could you please tell meaning and uses of 'would prefer to have'+p.p ?

Comment: "Would prefer to have" can entail some degree of regret or none at all, depending on context. For example, if your friend made a choice of the hotel, it is just a contradiction of thoughts and "would prefer to have stayed" simply implies that you would have made a different choice. "should have" implies a higher degree of regret. For example, you ended up choosing a cheaper hotel but it is outside the city and now you rue about it by saying that you should have stayed at the other hotel.

Comment: what did you understand from my comment and what question remains in your mind?

Comment: I would like you to answer the question: question itself is sufficient to express my problem

Comment: Can i replace those two sentences without changing their meanings

Comment: I think it would be better if you could try to to put an answer to this question so that i'll be able to point out what would be in my mind then.

Comment: I'v replaced those sentences using 'should'  is it correct? I think it would be better if you could try to to put an answer to this question so that i'll be able to point out what would be there in my mind then.

Comment: @vickyace I think you should expand your first comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

"Would prefer to have" can entail some degree of regret or none at all, depending on context.

> For example, you and your friend are to book a hotel. Your friend  chose the hotel based on his likings. Let us say he did so because it had bigger rooms. But the number of restaurants are too few.

You would have chosen a hotel  with rooms of average size but with greater number of restaurants for variety.

It is just a contradiction of thoughts and "would prefer to have stayed" "simply implies that you would have made a **different choice.**

It is also used in construction of **conditional statements.**

> Example - I would have succeeded if my luck helped.

"Should have" implies a higher or definite **degree of regret.**

> For example, you ended up choosing a cheaper hotel but it is outside the city and now you rue about it by saying that you should have stayed at the other hotel that your friend chose.

It is also used to **express disappointment.**

> You shouldn't have betrayed my friend.

So use "should have" when expressing regret or disappointment over one's or other's actions and "would have" when expressing choice or condition.

Edited- Expounding the comments.

It is tricky with "would" and "have." It depends on the construction/syntax.

**would like/love/prefer to** construction suggests preference or choice.

Whereas, **would have liked/loved/preferred** construction has more to do with regret and compunction.

Comment: sir,but I think when the preferences or choice  aren't filled, there must be a regret. so I'm confused with your answer.

Comment: @yubrajsharma First, don't call me sir. Second, you are convoluting your words. "would have" alone implies choice or preference. "I would have traveled by train" conveys preference just as much as "I would prefer to have traveled by train."

Comment: Your first comment doesn't involve would/should and is incorrect in construction.

Comment: Do you mean "sub+would prefer /like /love to have +p.p is used to express preferences and choice but not regret ?

Comment: But I think when the preferences or choice aren't fulfilled, there must be a regret. so I'm confused with your answer.

Comment: Could you please make it clear to me ? I'm confused here,

Comment: @yubrajsharma now you're clear with your question. It is a tricky thing with the words "would" and "have." I have explained it in the edited answer.

Comment: I'm afraid to say, you haven't involved 'past participle' in the construction: would like/prefer/love to have+past participle

(It's because we are talking about this construction)

Comment: Do you mean would like/love/prefer to have+past participle( i would like to have played) is the past tense of ''would like/prefer/love to+v1"( i would like to play)?

Comment: Where are you getting all this stuff from! They are not conjugations at all. "Would" is used for volition, hence it doesn't matter whether it is past, present or future. That is the general form and it goes with everything. Try http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/could-have-should-have-would-have.html and do some research yourself. Use oxford learners dictionary to learn different uses of modal verbs.

Comment: If it's true, i think it shows the likeness/preferences/desire of the speaker. AM I correct to say ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'conjugation ' ?

Comment: This is the first time i've heard the words 'volition' and 'conjugation'

Comment: @yubrajsharma I'm not gonna spoonfeed anymore. Look them up.

Comment: Please One thing to be discussed is that i'm not talking about past tense of would. But i'm talking about the past tense of 'would like/love/prefer to+ infinitive(without to). Please,this question is thought-provoking for me.. Is it past tense structure. ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma "I would prefer to have stayed elsewhere" "I would love to have traveled via air" "I would like to have loved by her" are all present tense. It is talking about the past but it is in present.

Comment: That's what i mean but the structure looks like past form